# tar – extract discarding directory structure

Tags: unix, zip, archiving, tar

`unzip` has a nifty option `-j`, whereby the directory structure of the archive is discarded, and all files are extracted into the same directory.

Is there a way of making `tar` work in the same way? Nothing in the man page seems to indicate so.

So, is there an alternative, preferably Free Software, tool that will do that?

Comment: Related: [Extracting the Contents of tar archive to parent directory](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/189937/80216).

Answer (score 99, accepted):

GNU tar lives on featuritis, so naturally also has some options for that.
http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/transform.html

If you just want to remove a few path segments, then `--strip-components=n` or `--strip=n` will often do:

```
 tar xvzf tgz --strip=1
```

But it's also possible to regex-rewrite the files to be extracted (flags are `--transform` or `--xform` and accept ereg with the `/x` modifer):

```
 tar xvzf tgz --xform='s#^[^/]+#.#x'
                 # or 's#^.+/##x' for discarding all paths
```

For listing a tar you need the additional `--show-transformed` option:

```
 tar tvzf tgz --show-transformed --strip=1 --xform='s/abc/xyz/x'
```

I believe the rewriting options also work for packing, not just for extracting. But `pax` has obviously a nicer syntax.

Comment: Why not `s#.*/##`?

Comment: --strip just made my day. Thanks!

Comment: `--strip` not mentioned in the os x tar man page, but it works anyway, thanks!

Comment: Far better than the accepted answer.

Comment: is there any difference between `--strip` and `--strip-components`?

Comment: @Joel It's the same.  That's just a shortened version of the full parameter name. Technically you could even say `--stri` or `--str`, since that's still unambiguous.

Answer (score 14):

You can do it fairly easily in two steps. Adapt as necessary:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/dirtree
$ tar xfz /path/to/archive -C /tmp/dirtree
$ find /tmp/dirtree -type f -exec mv -i {} . \;
$ rm -rf /tmp/dirtree
```

Comment: this is how i'd do it (using `find -exec mv -i` instead of `find | xargs`).... simple steps i can repeat on any system without having to carry around a script to do it for me.

Comment: +1, `tmpdir=$( mktemp -d )` is handy when creating temporary directories

Answer (score 8):

`pax` can do it:

```
pax -v -r -s '/.*\///p' < archive.tar
```

or

```
zcat archive.tar.gz | pax -v -r -s '/.*\///p'
```

You can check the name replacement operation first by omitting the `-r` option.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution that doesn't require installing anything.

1. use a `tar tvf` to grab all the files from the tarball
2. Extract those files individually - have tar extract to stdout & redirect to $filename

   ```
   tar -tvf $1 | grep -v "^d" | \
                 awk '{for(i=6;i<NF+1;i++) {printf "%s ",$i};print ""}' |\
                 while read filename
                 do
                    tar -O -xf $1 "$filename" > `basename "$filename"`
                 done
   ```

save as extract.sh and run as `extract.sh myfile.tar`.  It will also overwrite any duplicate filenames encountered in the directories pulled from the tarball.

Comment: Actually I just tested it on some a dir tree at home & It fails on files containing spaces.  I'll see if I can't post an update.

Comment: Fixed it, but it's not nearly as pretty as it was.

Answer (score -1):

```
tar xf foo.tar.gz foo/path/to/file/bar.mp3 -O > bar.mp3
```

The `-O` option extracts a file to standard out, and `>` redirects that output into a file. So in my example I'm extracting foo.mp3 and redirecting it into bar.mp3. The file names are arbitrary.