# extract files in sub-directories from a tar file to one directory

Tags: tar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tar – extract discarding directory structure](https://superuser.com/questions/71846/tar-extract-discarding-directory-structure)

I have a tar file that include sub-directories each has several files. I need to extract all those files into one directory. Any help?

Comment: Which operating system? Tag accordingly.

Comment: @DanielAndersson I am using Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Operating system not stated. Assuming some *nix-like variant.*

Assuming TAR file `tarfile.tar` in the current directory:

```
mkdir temp dirwithfiles
tar xvf tarfile.tar -C temp
find temp -type f -exec mv -i {} dirwithfiles \;
rm -r temp
```

This will extract the full directory structure, then move all files within to the `dirwithfiles` directory.

Note `mv -i` since there might be several files with the same filename that need to be selected from.

Comment: It's almost uncanny how similar this is to the accepted answer in the question that was later linked as a duplicate. It's obvious enough to not qualify for a patent, though, so I think I'm in the clear.