# Change the directory structure in tar.gz without extracting it

Tags: linux, tar, gzip

I have a tar.gz file that has the following structure when I extract.
/dir1/dir2/dir3/many_text_files(.txt)

I would like to change the structure as dir3/many_text_files(.txt)

A simple solution is to extract it and archive again using the -C option.

But, I am wondering if there is any elegant way to do this without extracting and archiving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several solutions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26105/rename-directory-inside-of-a-tar-archive), but to modify it you need to gunzip it first. The suggested hack is nice.

In your case, I'd just extract files [disregarding dir structure](https://superuser.com/a/377247/458082), all into a new `dir3` (if I understand correctly what's in your tarball)